# How Can I Tap The Detail Button Of An UITableViewCell in Xcode UI Test?

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

I have an `UITableViewCell` configured with a detail button and an accessibility identifier:

```swift
private func configure(cell: UITableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    // ...
    cell.accessoryType = .detailButton
    cell.accessoryView?.accessibilityLabel = "Item Details"
    // ...
}
```

In the UI test method, I need to tap the detail button of the cell, which I attempt in the following method:

```swift
private func getScreenshotOfItemToEdit() {
    app.tables.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 0).buttons["Item Details"].tap()
    itemQuantityTextField().tap()
    itemQuantityTextField().typeText("2")
    snapshot("04-EditItem")
    saveItemBarButtonItem().tap()
}
```

The test fails at the first line, but I can't figure out why.

What do I need to change so that I can tap the detail button of the cell in my UI test?

Comment: Please post the error message and the view hierarchy information available for the cell

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the item you're trying to interact with exists I would suggest you to print the application's debug description

```
print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)
```

This will give you all the elements that are on the screen along with their accessibility identifier, label and value.

After using the code you provided, I wasn't actually able to set the `accessibilityLabel` of the `accessoryView` to `"Item Details"`. Setting the `accessibilityIdentifier` did not work either.

The good new is that you can still access the detail button out of the box with the following code

```
// Accessing the detail button for the first cell
let cell = XCUIApplication().cells.element(boundBy: 0)
cell.buttons["More Info"]
```